# Is it appropriate to ask for help locating specific photos or photographers?

Tags: discussion

Five years ago, I stumbled into a photoshoot, and was asked to join in. But I have never seen any of the photos of myself, and I have exhausted my search options.

I have the name of the (paid) model, a sample photo from the photoshoot (not including myself), and the approximate date and location for the shoot. As far as I can see, the question does not violate any of the "don't"s on how to ask questions here. But is doesn't really include any of the "do's" either.

Would this kind of question be acceptable on photography stack exchange?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, questions like those are likely to get closed very quickly as they're not really about photography in any meaningful sense. These are really investigation requests that happen to involve photographs and photographers and that's kind of incidental to the real issue.

Comment: Thanks guys. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Usually these are on topic if they are about historically relevant images or photographers, but beyond that scope they are not.

Comment: Thanks guys. Much appreciated.